# Cannot get to parent Sharepoint URL. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_web' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to save a value to a sharepoint list. I can save it to the subsite list using "SP.ClientContext.get_current();" with no problems. However,  I want to save it to a list of the same name only on the partent site using the URL. The get following error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_web' of undefined**

```
            var siteUrl;
            siteUrl = '/sites/Mysite/';
            var clientContext = SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);/*.get_current();*/
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('QuizResults');


            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

            var vURL = (document.URL);
            var vScore = 'score';
            var vDate = new Date();

            oListItem.set_item('Title', vURL);
            oListItem.set_item('Score', vScore);
            oListItem.set_item('Date', vDate);
            oListItem.update();
            clientContext.load(oListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));


            function onQuerySucceeded()
            {
            ('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
            }
            function onQueryFailed(args)
            {
            ('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }   

            //end of section for adding score to list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks John-M, but I actually resolved this by doing the following:

```
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var oList = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('QuizResults');
```

The added part being the ".get_site().get_rootWeb()"

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `SP.ClientContext(siteUrl)` function (constructor) instead of calling `get_current()`, you should use it with the `new` keyword to instantiate a new context.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.(siteUrl);
```

The `get_current()` function returns the context appropriate for the current page/site. When you pass in a URL you need to actually create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Open new site for rootsite with site url

```
  string rootSiteUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url;
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(rootSiteUrl ))
           {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.GetList("QuizResults");

                //Add item here


            }
        }
```